# Add one click operation for two different input[type="submit"] (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons

```
<input type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
<input type="submit" id="close" value="Close">
```

I want to add only one click operation for both of them

Sample Idea:

```
$('#update || #close').click(function(){ // If update OR close button is clicked       

  //do something here

});
```

**Is it possible?**

or I have to write two different click operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma separate [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$('#update,#close').click(function(){ // If update OR close button is clicked           
  //do something here    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#update,#close').click(function(){ // If update OR close button is clicked       

  //do something here

});
```

Use comma (,) to seperate selectors ...

Comment: Pretty obvious ripoff of @Pranav's answer... :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma,

```
$('#update, #close').click(function(){
  //do something here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#update, #close').on('click', function(){
            //do something here
        });
    });
```